Recognised LEGO Fan Media Days 2017 - Sponsorship Proposal
Recognised LEGO Fan Media Days 2017
What?
The Recognised LEGO Fan Media Days 2017 is a three-day event hosted by The LEGO Group for Ambassadors of LEGO User Groups.

The LEGO Ambassador Network (LAN) is a community network to provide
  valuable dialogue and initiate activities of relevance for the mutual
  benefit of the Recognized LEGO User Groups (RLUG), the Recognized LEGO
  Fan Media (RLFM) and The LEGO Group (TLG).

(I have been asked by jncraton (our current Ambassador from LEGO Answers to The LEGO Group) to attend this event on his behalf as he is unable to do so.)
Over the three days TLG will be providing presentations, a LEGO House/LEGOLAND tour, interviews, discussions/feedback as well as a 'secret unveiling'.
Where?
Billund, Denmark 
(various locations including within walking distance)
When?
31st May - 2nd June 2017
Why?
This event will be a big opportunity to promote the LEGO Stack Exchange website amongst other LEGO fan and media websites, and possibly get answers to some of our unanswered questions on the site. 
I will be given the chance to give a presentation to TLG and other RLFM groups about our community. This will also be the first time that LEGO Answers has attended an official event hosted by The LEGO Group.
In addition to attending the event and providing a presentation I pledge to:

Produce a photo report of the event, which I will share with the
LEGO.SE community on Meta.
Share additional photographs from the event on my personal Flickr
account. (You can find photos from when I previously
attended Brick 2014)


Abbreviations

TLG - The LEGO Group
RLFM - Recognized LEGO Fan Media
SE - Stack Exchange

